# ElasticSearch: how to find an es index in all node index rate

Tags: elasticsearch

I find the node disk usage is not balanced. The shards are balanced. So I think it is some index some shard index rate is speed more.

Answer (score 0):

They might be couple of reason for such a behavior:

- Your setup for Index not matching number of nodes regarding primary and replica shards. For example if you have 3 Nodes recommendation would be to have  maximum 3 primary shards and 1 replica, if you don't follow this you will have more pressure o couple of your Nodes.
- When you have custom Id generator, the reason behind is elastic using routing to decide in which node the document should be indexed For more information check Elasticsearch routing [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-routing-field.html).

`routing_factor = num_routing_shards / num_primary_shards`

`shard_num = (hash(_routing) % num_routing_shards) / routing_factor`

- Deleting document and Segment merging as well can cause such a behavior.